# Convert pdf file into image and then blur some part of image again convert image into pdf

Tags: php, image, pdf, blur, imagick

I am working like taking a pdf file and converting it into Image
Then blur some sensitive part of image. Now this blurred image again converting pdf.
this is my requirement.

I have tried with Imagick library but it gives me error

$pdfPath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blurImage\prescription.pdf';
$imagick = new Imagick();

$imagick->readImage($pdfPath);

$imagick->setResolution(300, 300);

$imagick->setImageFormat('png');

$imagick->writeImage('prescription.png');

$imagick->destroy();

It gives me following error

Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gs" -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -
dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-
sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" -dPrinted=false "-
sOutputFile=C:/Users/VIJAY~1.CHA/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-S7WCdJ5qenRElIaz_gXRVgs-RwnWkN9M%d" "-
fC:/Users/VIJAY~1.CHA/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-yFAzolPZHrIRPrJ9VfGrPJmtR-YzG003" "-
fC:/Users/VIJAY~1.CHA/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-oUCzJGgKpWv--RLj-JyOJEdWj0mfoFDS"' (The system
cannot find the file specified. ) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/516 in
C:\xampp\htdocs\blurImage\index.php:43 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\blurImage\index.php(43):
Imagick->readImage('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #1 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\blurImage\index.php on line 43

Comment: Do you have Ghostscript installed ? Is it available in the $PATH environment variable ? You seem to be using Windows. On Windows the Ghostscript executable is not called 'gs' it is one of gswin32, gswin33c, gswin64 or gswin64c depending on whether the installation is 32 or 64-bit and you want to use the 'w'indow or 'c'ommand line application. You'll probably have to change the ImageMagick configuration to make this work, I cannot tell you how to do that.

Comment: @KenS  I have installed imagick extension on local server xampp I have checked it with phpinfo(). It is fine but my question how can install Ghostscript  and ImageMagick- exe file on Dev server